# How to split tables for effective database design?

Tags: database, normalization

Suppose I have 3 tables in my database each one representing a specific type of lands differentiating by their size. First I have a line, which represents the biggest land entity. Each lines contains many projects which are smaller land entities. And each project contains many plots which are the smallest entity.

I created a table for each one of them in order to store their information. However, I noticed that they had some columns in common such as the state, town and city and also, those columns can contain duplicate information : Many plots can be in the same state and city, so we will have the same info repeated in many rows.

I have three questions:

1- How can I effectively split the tables to avoid redundancy? I tought about creating a new table only for geographic info, but how to organize data to also avoid redundancy in this table?

2- Since a line contain many projects which itself contains many plots; this means that a line contains many plots. Should I then create a FK relationship between plot and both of line and project?

3- In case I create another table for geographical info, what would be a good choice of primary key for it? ( In order to use it as FK in the other tables).

Answer (score 0):

> 1- How can I effectively split the tables to avoid redundancy? I
>   tought about creating a new table only for geographic info, but how to
>   organize data to also avoid redundancy in this table?

You can create an `address` table with a `id`, `state`, `town` and `city` fields and a composite unique key, covering all fields except `id`. Each of your land plots table will refer to this `address` table by it's PK. You will have to insert data into this table only if you have some new address combination. But this will increase support costs and I don't think you should. I am ok with some duplication like that (assuming, you store only ids of states, cities etc in your land plots table of course).

> 2- Since a line contain many projects which itself contains many
>   plots; this means that a line contains many plots. Should I then
>   create a FK relationship between plot and both of line and project?

No. Children should generally refer only to their direct parents unless you have a good reason to violate this rule.

> 3- In case I create another table for geographical info, what would be
>   a good choice of primary key for it? ( In order to use it as FK in the
>   other tables).

I believe surrogate primary key is ok here if you make your table like this: `id`, `state_id`, `town_id` and `city_id`. But, as I've said, I do not think this degree of normalisation is necessary.